# Could not get unknown property 'artifactory_contextUrl' for root project '[redacted]' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: java, spring, gradle

So let me give some background on this before you start making assumptions. I have been facing a torturous process of debugging Gradle since I began working at my current place of employ. Collectively my coworkers and I have spent close to 20 hours trying different things to get Gradle to play nicely on my machine. It's finally to the point where it's completely halted my ability to work.

**IMPORTANT NOTE: I am the only one who gets this error, and we are all using the exact same code, so the problem isn't here, but here is my build.gradle (minus redactions) for reference. My stacktrace will be below. Please help.**

Gradle version: 5.6.2

IDE: IntelliJ (latest as of 9/30/19)

OS: Win 10 pro

```
version = "${version != 'unspecified' ? version : 'your-default-version'}"

apply plugin: 'java'

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
apply plugin: 'docker'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: "com.github.ManifestClasspath"
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath 'se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2'
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4+"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.viswaramamoorthy:gradle-util-plugins:0.1.0-RELEASE"
    }
}



repositories {
    mavenCentral()
jcenter()
}
springBoot {
    mainClassName = "com.[redacted].Application"
    buildInfo {
        properties {
            artifact = group
            version = version
            group =group
            name = name
        }
    }
}


ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Greenwich.SR2'
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.lmax', name: 'disruptor', version: '3.4.2'

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'

    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client')


    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign')
    compile group: 'io.github.openfeign', name: 'feign-okhttp', version: '10.1.0'

    implementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin')
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
    compile('com.github.gavlyukovskiy:p6spy-spring-boot-starter:1.5.5')

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-aop'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.retry', name: 'spring-retry'


    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jdk8', version: '2.9.7'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.9.7'

    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'

    compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '7.2.1.jre11'

    compile 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-elastic:latest.release'
    compile group: 'com.vlkan.log4j2', name: 'log4j2-logstash-layout', version: '0.16'

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2")
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-yaml', version: '2.9.7'

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
configurations {
    compile.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

task buildDocker (type: Docker,dependsOn: bootJar){
    project.group="[redacted]"
    applicationName=jar.baseName
    push=true
    dockerfile=file('src/main/docker/Dockerfile')
    doFirst{
        copy {
            from(jar)
            into(stageDir)
            rename(applicationName+"-"+version,applicationName)
        }


    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'gradle-dev-local'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true

        }
        Defaults {
            publications ('mavenJava')
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'gradle-dev-local'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true

        }
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project '[redacted]'.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:92)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:211)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:66)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:48)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor$1.run(BuildScriptProcessor.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:200)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:186)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:41)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject$1.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:226)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:220)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:186)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:95)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:695)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:143)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:60)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:41)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:302)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:210)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:58)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:82)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:55)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:58)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'artifactory_contextUrl' for root project '[redacted]' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getMissingProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:83)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.getMissingProperty(BasicScript.java:155)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:61)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.getProperty(BasicScript.java:64)
        at build_dci24fwfxv8gatatq6iqhoy7d$_run_closure8.doCall(C:\Users\[redacted\build.gradle:137)
        at build_dci24fwfxv8gatatq6iqhoy7d$_run_closure8.doCall(C:\Users\[redacted]\build.gradle)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.dsl.ArtifactoryPluginConvention.artifactory(ArtifactoryPluginConvention.groovy:40)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:479)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:191)
        at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultConvention$ExtensionsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(DefaultConvention.java:316)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:33)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BasicScript.java:133)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:160)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.invokeMethod(BasicScript.java:82)
        at build_dci24fwfxv8gatatq6iqhoy7d.run(C:\Users\[redacted]\build.gradle:136)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:90)
        ... 127 more
```

If any more information is needed to help me, please let me know. I'm running a fresh reinstall of IntelliJ as well as a reinstall of gradle. Which did not fix my problems, and ultimately probably made them worse since I can't import projects with Gradle now.

Many thanks.

Comment: 1)What IDE are you using? 2) do you have this issue when running gradle from outside IDE?

Comment: 1) I edited in that I'm using the most recent IntelliJ 2) and I didn't before, but I do now. Oh, and one more thing, the build.gradle files in our projects haven't had any changes made to the problem areas since I started working here, it's all just kinda failed around me.

Comment: you have the issue when building from terminal?

Comment: Any gradle or wrapper command fails nearly instantly with that issue. Also, I have properly set up GRADLE_HOME and its respective path variables. I have also confirmed that Gradle is in fact installed via the "gradle -v" command.

Comment: Like, I mean everything. bootJar, bootRun, build, clean. Everything fails instantly and this actually just suddenly happened at one point. No system changes were made, no code changes were made, I didn't download any new gradle installations, nothing. It just stopped working one day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My **gradle.properties** file was missing with the username, PW, and URL. Replacing it with that information allowed me to import projects again and perform non-bootRun Gradle tasks.

It got deleted at some point before I reinstalled Gradle and I never replaced it due to panic that my Gradle wasn't working any longer.

Well, it's still not properly working, but I can import projects again, so I can at least get by with IntelliJ's compiler.